# aws boto pass variable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, ssm

```
ssm = boto3.client('ssm' )
            instance = 'i-123123'
            response = ssm.send_command( InstanceIds=[ instance ], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Comment='slack testing', Parameters={ "commands":[ "hostname" ]  } )
            command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
            command_id.encode("utf-8")
            output = ssm.get_command_invocation(
                CommandId=command_id,
                InstanceId=instance
                )
```

Above is the code . the issue is in get_command_invocation its is not passing as varibale but passing as string and throing below error

```
An error occurred (InvocationDoesNotExist) when calling the GetCommandInvocation operation: : InvocationDoesNotExist
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 137, in lambda_handler
InstanceId=instance
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
InvocationDoesNotExist: An error occurred (InvocationDoesNotExist) when calling the GetCommandInvocation operation:
```

but if i separately   print command_id and instance they are actually printing the actual id.

What will the solution for this?

Comment: i could be wrong but shouldn't response = ssm.send_command actually be client.send_command?

Comment: ssm = boto3.client('ssm' ) i stored it in ssm variable

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just set sleep/wait into the code .
time.sleep(10) into the code resolved the issue